# login from one application to another without sso solution

Tags: single-sign-on, idm

I have two web applications (A and B). I need to login to application B from Application A.
what is the best and secure way to handle this, keep in mind that I don't have IDM solution to manage single sign on?

Comment: Then, use IDM solution to manage single sign on.

Comment: I dont have IDM. I need an alternative way